# Caching of constants in OPA?

Tags: performance, open-policy-agent, rego

Somewhat contrived example perhaps, but for a top level assignment like this:

`cache_duration_seconds := 60 * 60 * 24 * 30`

Does OPA recognize the value as constant and persist it between requests, or is it going to be calculated per invocation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OPA will memoize the value generated by the rule and cache it for the duration of the policy query. In other words, in this case, if `cache_duration_seconds` is referenced multiple times in the policy, it will be computed once and then re-used at each location. The next time the policy is queried, the value be computed again.